# Create local http listener in java

Tags: java, android, apache, httplistener

I have downloaded the Android Developer Documentations and I can access them from my own machine with the following url

```
file:///home/farhad/Documents/androidsdk/docs/index.html
```

Now what I want to do, is to create an Http Listener, preferably using java, to redirect the links of Android Developer Documentations to my localhost version. By this I mean that, when I enter or click on a link with this destination :

```
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html
```

I want my http listener to redirect me automatically to :

```
file:///home/farhad/Documents/androidsdk/docs/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html
```

replacing the `https://developer.android.com` with `file:///home/farhad/Documents/androidsdk/docs`

So how can I implement such application using java ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using similar thing for my testing with jetty server, 
please download jetty-server-xxx.jar, I am using eclipse
and eclipse has this jar package. Once you run this, 
you can browse files like http://localhost/xyz.html 
and localhost will be the root directory of code 
and for other machines it will be the ip of machine where server is running. Hope this helps.

```
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;

    import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
    import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
    import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
    import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler;

    Server server;
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileServerLib.class.getName());

    public void FTPStart(int portnumber) 
    {
        try
        {
            logger.info("Starting file server at port: "+portnumber);

            this.server = new Server(portnumber);

            ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
            resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);

            resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "index.html" });

            resource_handler.setResourceBase(".");
            logger.info("serving " + resource_handler.getBaseResource());

            HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
            handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { resource_handler, new DefaultHandler() });
            this.server.setHandler(handlers);

            boolean flag = this.server.isRunning();

            if(flag)
            {
                logger.info("Server is already running: ");

            }
            else
            {
                logger.info("Starting FTP Server : ");
                this.server.start();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.info("Automation Script is not able to start FTP Server at port :" + portnumber, e);
        }

    }
```